# IBInspectable: extracting data from value failed

Tags: ios, swift, ibinspectable

I have built [a library](https://github.com/linusgeffarth/LGSegmentedControl) that adds a view to the screen and allows the developer to customize its appearance by entering custom values in `IBInspectable` fields.

It used to work just fine, except when I added the *localizable* branch. I noticed that the custom values entered in the storyboard aren't applied to the view.
I started debugging and printed the `IBInspectable`s' values. Xcode gave me this:

> extracting data from value failed

Any idea why that's happening, and what I can do about it?

Comment: It's weird, there is nothing strange from `1.2 to 1.2.1` and neither from `1.1.2 to 1.2` in your releases. Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: I just removed the release so people don't upgrade to a dysfunctional version. I'm talking about the code that is in the `localizable` branch. Try that one.

Comment: I just ran your localize branch, and setting initialSelectedIndex from Storyboard does work for me. Can you tell me how to exactly reproduce this?

Comment: So the localizable branch aims to integrate Localize, an external library for localizing things. I added an `IBInspectable` property `segmentTitleKeys` to the control. Those keys are then taken, localized, and then assigned as titles. When setting the keys in storyboard of the example project, the issue occurred. Notice how it completely ignores the colors you set in the storyboard.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `updateSelection` inside `LGSegmentedControl.swift` and then do `p options`. In there, it said *extracting data from value failed* for me.